# Tub only leaks when filled and plug removed

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

my tenants called stating that water is pouring from their walls. They live on the second floor.  A new tub was installed directly above on the third floor and has been used only for showering without any water dripping this past week.  The tub was filled and when the drain was opened, this is when the leak occurred. They showered the next day and no water leak.  Only when large volume at once to drain.  Is there some overflow that can't handle all this volume/ pressure?  Thanks. Jill

Comment: I had the same problem with a kitchen sink: all OK with running water, leak when removing the plug after washing the dishes. The problem was an open junction for the dishwasher's waste water outlet.

Answer (score 2):

There's no pressure/overflow inside the walls that would explain this. There is a tub overflow that connects to these same drain lines, and due to their position, they could be partially related to the actual problem.

This indicates the drain lines have a leak, likely a bad glue joint on the top of the drain line near the trap. If there's any partial blockage further down the drain that would worsen this issue. The tub overflow is also connected on the top side of these drain lines, and if it's improperly connected, that would be another example of a bad joint on the top of the drain line.

You'll need to open up the wall or the ceiling below to find and correct this bad drain line.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a poorly fitted waste outlet in the bath.

When plastic bathtubs are filled with water they change shape slightly due to the considerable weight of water. This can move the connections to the waste pipe slightly.

It might also just be due to the higher pressure of a tub full of water and the higher flow rates when draining.

The waste connection needs to be removed cleaned up and reconnected carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Unscrew the drain flange, remove the old plumbers putty, apply fresh putty and retighten.  Weight from water in tub might be causing a slight separation between flange and tub. I use silicone instead of plumbers putty. No leaks.